# How to stop a .msi installer requesting Admin credentials

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7

I have created a .msi installer for office 2013 and saved it to a network share on a 2008 standard server so that my users can download it, unfortunately when they try to install it on windows 7 computers UAC requests admin credentials to allow the installer to run, all users have been setup with NTFS permissions on the file to read write and execute. can anyone do me a step by step guide on how to get the installer to install without needing admin credentials?

Comment: Your users aren't local administrators, but you trust them to install their own copy of Office?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to provide software to users that installs upon their request without them having administrative rights is self-service systems.

Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager has been doing this for years. You can even set it up so that users see the regular shortcuts for Word etc, and that the software isn't installed until the user tries to open up the application.

Microsoft System Center Service Manager can provide a pretty neat self-service portal, where users can request software (or assets in general). This is also driven by the SCCM agent.

Answer (score 0):

Read and write permissions on the file don't really have anything to do with it.

To install Office requires quite a few changes to the client system - new folders and files in various program folders, changes to the registry, etc. These changes *will* need administrator privileges on the local machine. If these changes didn't need admin privileges, any program could make dangerous changes to the local system - this is what UAC is designed to control.

If it's prompting for admin credentials then obviously the user doesn't have sufficient privileges to make the required changes to their system. You could make them all local administrators on their computer, which should then just prompt them with a 'Do you want to allow this program to make changes to this computer' yes/no dialog, but that's a silly thing to do just so users can install Office.

Really, you're going to have to accept that installing software requires administrator privileges on the computer you are installing to. Having some way around requiring admin credentials would defeat the purpose of having UAC in the first place.

If your users log onto a domain it may be possible to deploy Office automatically using group policy but that's not something I can help you with.